# 'Invalid term in model formula' when calling R.armaFit

Tags: r, f#, r.net, fslab

I'm getting this message:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
>
> invalid term in model formula

When calling this code:

```
let data : float[] = // ...
R.eval(R.parse(text="library(fArma)")) |> ignore

let dataset =
    namedParams["XX", box data]
    |> R.data_frame

let fitted = R.armaFit(formula="XX ~ arma(1 , 1)", data=dataset)
```

The error is triggered by the last line.

I've tried removing the `box`, the `XX ~`, but I get the same result.

I was trying to follow this guide:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/arma-models-for-trading/

The log reports this:

> [03/02/17 18:01:46] [Pid:10004, Tid:1, Apid:1]
>   eval(base::`data.frame`(XX=fsr_10004_3)) [03/02/17 18:01:46]
>   [Pid:10004, Tid:1, Apid:1] Output:  [03/02/17 18:01:50] [Pid:10004,
>   Tid:1, Apid:1] eval(fArma::`armaFit`(formula=fsr_10004_4,
>   data=fsr_10004_5)) [03/02/17 18:01:50] [Pid:10004, Tid:1, Apid:1]
>   Output: Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    invalid term
>   in model formula
>
> [03/02/17 18:01:50] [Pid:10004, Tid:1, Apid:1] Operation failed:
>   RDotNet.EvaluationException: Error in terms.formula(formula, data =
>   data) :    invalid term in model formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let armaFit = R.armaFit(R.as_formula("xx ~ arma(1,1)"), dataset)
```